# Approximate Identities

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

**Statement** : Let $U$ be a C* algebra and$\lambda=\left\{A\in U:A\geq 0, ||A||<1\right\}$. If $B\in \lambda$ then if $X\in U$

$$||X^*(I-B)^2X||\leq ||X^*(I-B)X||$$

For reference this is from Davidson's $C^*$ Algebras by Example, where he proves that every $C^*$ algebra has an approximate identity.

**Question** how do they arrive at that inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that:
$$0\leq(I-B)^2\leq(I-B)$$
*(Not sure about that point!)*

Then apply:
$$0\leq A\leq B\implies X^*AX\leq X^*BX$$

Exploit that:
$$0\leq A\leq B:\quad\|A\|\leq\|B\|$$
*(That is crucial of positive elements!)*

Comment: That's what I had though at first but I couldn't verify $(I-B)^2\leq (I-B)$.

Comment: @S.S: And it doesn't necessarily hold? Hmm that is at least not nice.

Comment: No, I just wasn't able show that the result holds. I'll try to look at it again later and see if it is indeed true.

Answer (score 2):

Using the ordering suggested by Freez_S we get that 
$$ (I-B)^2\leq (I-B)$$This is the same as showing
$$0\leq B(I-B)$$
after a little bit of rearrangement.

Now we see this in terms of the continuous functional calculus. We note that in the sub algebra $C^*(B)$ there exists an element associated to the continuous function $f(x)=x(1-x)$ namely $f(B)=B(I-B)$. Since the spectra of this element is contained in the image of $f(x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ we see that $B(I-B)$ has non-negative spectra. Since the spectra of $B$ in our original algebra $U$ is a subset of the spectra with respect to $C^*(B)$; it follows that $B(I-B)$ is a positive element, the self adjointness being obvious.

Comment: Very good !! ;)

Comment: Equivalently, you can exploit that $B':=1-B\geq0$ so for $f(x):=x^2$ and $g(x):=x$ one has $f(B')\leq g(B')$.

Comment: Moreover, you can check even that for $h(x):=(1-x)-(1-x)^2$ one has $h(x)\geq0$ for all $0\leq x\leq1$. *(Though yours is much nicer!)*